# Without run-time permission in Oreo, how can I make an Android application to install the third party sdk files automatically in a folder?

Tags: performance, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to install the Android application in Oreo devices. Application is getting installed but the third party SDK is not getting installed automatically once the application starts to run. Inside the application, it is showing lots of pop up to make a user to allow / deny the SDK to install. If the user is denied, then this third party SDK will not be installed.

My question is, how to make an Android application to download the third party SDK automatically once when the android application has been installed in Oreo mobile devices without showing a pop up dialogs to the user to make them to select manually with choices like "Allow" or "Deny" the package installation.

Can I add this permission in Manifest to make an application to install the unknown applications automatically?

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

My concern is, new users or customers do not have idea for what purpose this package is getting installed while using Android app. If the user has denied the third party SDK then the Android application will not be more beneficial for the users.

How can I make an Android app accept the payment SDK and download it automatically without run time permissions in Oreo?

Comment: What is the context of the link in this question? It has not been introduced, and so its relevance to the core question is not clear. Read the question through please, and merge the link into an appropriate point.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question with a clear context@halfer

Comment: OK. In the meantime (two hours later) I have removed the link, since it makes so sense without an introduction. Feel free to add it back in if you can introduce it properly.

Comment: I don't develop for Android, but it looks like you want your app to install third-party software without users' permission. I hope that is impossible for security reasons. Would it not be better for you to integrate this into your app, so that a download is not required?

Comment: Yeah... cannot restrict the security reasons since in lower version devices, we are allowing third party apps to get downloaded / installed without any user-permissions